# Differential equations with power series method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using power series method solve $$tx''(t) - tx'(t) - x(t) = 0 , \\ x(0)=0, \\ x'(0)=1$$

We can take $$x(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$
Furthermore we have $$x'(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1} \\ x''(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}$$

Then I substituted it to $tx''(t) - tx'(t) - x(t) = 0$ and I received $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_nt^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^{n} = 0$$

What can I do next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hints: Get all the powers in the summations the same, Get all of the ranges of the summations the same, Write the general terms for the constants, Solve for those terms

Comment: You will discover the recurrence relation between the coefficients.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the first series in your last equation; it should be $t^{n-1}$ and not $t^{n-2}$?

Comment: I would recommend writing $x(t) = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2+a_3t^3+a_4t^4+\cdots$ to start with. Do the differentiations, make the substitutions, apply the initial conditions and then simplify. Most questions only ask for the first few terms (the $k$-jet) of $x$ anyway. If you're asked for the whole thing, then starting with finite terms will help you see any patterns.

Comment: You should get a series that is the expansion of $x(t) = t~e^t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$
x(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n
$$
is a solution of the DE
$$
tx''-tx'-x=0,
$$
then we have
$$
0=t\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}-t\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nt^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)\left[na_{n+1}-a_n\right]t^n.
$$
It follows that
$$
na_{n+1}-a_n=0 \quad \forall n \ge 0
$$
with
$$
a_0=x(0)=0,\ a_1=x'(0)=1.
$$
Thus for every $n \ge 2$ we have
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n-1}\ldots\frac{1}{2-1}a_{2-1}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}.
$$
We then deduce that
$$
x(t)=t+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!}t^n=t+t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}t^n=t+t(e^t-1)=te^t.
$$